# React performance: what's a good guide for an upper limit on number of components?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React, Bootstrap and Typescript.

I've built a list/edit screen that can contain up to 200 rows (100 "list" rows and 100 "detail" rows).
Each "detail" row contains a complete HTML form - they are hidden by default (inside a Bootstrap "Collapse" component) until the user starts editing them.

Please note, this is a learning exercise; I'm trying to get a feel for how far I can push React in terms of complexity of the UI before I start to see performance issues.
I'm not looking for a solution for this page specifically - there's lots of UX things I could do, limit rows per page, split the detail out into its own screen, use a modal dialog, etc.

[image: The UI]

The list and detail components are implemented as "PureComponent" and the state objects involved are all immutable Typescript objects (lists are implemented using Immutable.js).
I'd estimate there are about 1500 - 2000 React components involved with rendering this page.

I'm quite happy with the level of code complexity behind this implementation - it's easy to read and change and I'm confident that in a real app, as the complexity increases over time the implementation will remain maintainable.

But the performance is not quite what I'd hoped for.
I'm measuring this page with the Chrome performance tab with "?react_perf" URL.
With 100 entities,the "User Timing" in Chrome shows me that the "Table [update]" is taking between 60 - 90 milliseconds.

[image: performance]

That seems like quite a long time, I know these numbers aren't representative of production performance, given I'm using the development version of React to do the performance timing.
And the app does perform better when it's compiled for production - performance is Ok on a fairly standard desktop corporate machine or an iPhone6.  You can see the lag if you're really looking for it, but it's barely noticeable.
But on slower hardware (Samsung Galaxy Tablet, and an old Samsung phone) - the lag is quite noticeable.

I'm trying to understand if I should be looking for major mistakes/bottlenecks or is this about the kind of performance I should be expecting for this many components?

Possible improvements:

- the obvious major thing I can do is reducing the number of React components by not rendering all those detail forms unless the user expands the entity

  - that certainly improves the performance - table update time goes down to about 20 - 30 millis in development, pretty much undetectable especially in production.
- people are, inevitably, going to suggest using Redux

  - if I were to do that, what kind of performance increase would you expect so see?
  - my guess is that a Redux implementation wouldn't actually do much for performance (unless I'm making some major mistake that Redux will guide me toward avoiding)

So the question is:

> "what is a reasonable upper limit for the number of components a React
>   page should have"?

Or alternatively:

> "is 50+ milliseconds to do an update reasonable for a screen of this size"?

If my implementation is not horribly incorrect, then this exercise leaves me thinking my general performance guidance would be:

- "try to stay below about 500 React components on any given screen"

Comment: "people are, inevitably, going to suggest using Redux" - i won't. redux is good for separation of concerns and not for improving performance. If anything, the opposite it true many time. bring state from redux store to react component to improve performance

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/garbles/why-did-you-update to see if you are updating your components when you don't need to

Comment: @MukeshSoni  Agree strongly

Answer (score 0):

I think benchmarking for your particular scenario is a must as you have done.

Make sure you are keying your elements properly and maybe implement shouldComponentUpdate manually to short cut as much as possible.

Comment: @Shorn Edited the question a bit so it should be possible to revert. However have you checked my tips? 500 components shouldn't be an issue, not in my apps at least. When having many objects in a list an "infiny-scroll" feature might help performance too

Comment: I'm not looking for ways to restructure the page - I'm trying to get an idea of a useful "maximum components" to aim for with React.  As for "shouldComponentUpdate" - as stated in the question - I am using PureComponents (which brings a shallowCompare shouldComponentUpdate() implementation by default).  Also, I'm not saying 500 components is an issue: 500 is my current guess as to a usable goal for a "maximum components" guideline.  What might be helpful to me though, is to know how many max components do you use in your apps, and what kind of update times do you see?